# Django: Group query_set by answer

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the following out but:

*{'male': 123, 'female': 432, 'other': 12}*

From there I will go and calculate the % of the distribution to the total amount:

male: 123/567 = 21%
female: 76%
[...]

Currently, that's my not working solution. The output is not what I expected. What can I try next?

```
def get_gender_distribution(self):
    answers = (
        Question.objects.filter(
            focus=QuestionFocus.GENDER,
            survey__event=self.request.event,
            survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
        )
        .values('answers')
        .annotate(count=Count('answers'))
    )
```

****init****

```
class QuestionFocus(Choices):
    AGE = 'age'
```

**Models:**

```
class Question(TimeStampedModel[...]):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(related_name='questions')
    type = models.CharField([...])
    focus = models.CharField([...])

class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(related_name='answers')
    response = models.ForeignKey(related_name='answers')
    answer = models.TextField([...])

class Survey(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(related_name='surveys')
    template = models.CharField([...])
```

Comment: Where is `QuestionFocus`?

Comment: I added it. But it's just a string.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont know from which field `male`, `female` and `other` come from

Comment: @JoeyCoder Is your annotate query working as expected?

Comment: male, female etc. are saved as strings in the `answer` field @OlivierPons 
@JayVasant currently I just get back the values of the Question model and annotated something like that here `'answers__answer__count': 1`

Answer (score 0):

The query you may need is:

`Question.objects.values('focus').annotate(gender_count=Count('focus'))`

This will return the count of values of all the fields in `focus` of `Question`.

Then you can use the obtained dict to find the required ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
def get_gender_distribution(self):
    answers = Question.objects.filter(
                  focus=QuestionFocus.GENDER,
                  survey__event=self.request.event,
                  survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
              )
              .values('answers')
              .annotate(total=Count('answers'))
```

Maybe look another way: [`aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)